# How to specify the custom formatting on the XmlWriter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

After executing Serialize my XML looks like

```
<Prisinfo>
  <Enhet>kr</Enhet> 
  <Mengde>4.000000</Mengde> 
- <Delmengder>
- <Delmengde>
  <Mengde>2.000000</Mengde> 
  <Tekst>tekst</Tekst> 
  <Egenskaper /> 
  </Delmengde>
  </Delmengder>
  <Enhetspris>100.000000000000</Enhetspris> 
  <Sum>400.000000000000000000</Sum>
```

I need a way to control decimal numbers formating. Unfortunately, I have not found a solution.

Comment: What XML serializer are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to specify

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your class with string representation of decimal field formatted as you need and mark decimal field with `XmlIgnore` attribute, e.g.:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class X
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public decimal Dec { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Dec")]
    public string DecString
    {
        get
        {
            return Dec.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        set
        {
            Dec = decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```